# First steps in celery(d) 3.0.9

Tags: django-celery, djcelery

In two shells, on the same machine, I do the following:

a) /home/user/prod/env/bin/python /home/user/prod/www/devcode/manage.py celery worker -E

and celery starts up, apparently with no problems

b) /home/user/prod/env/bin/activate && /home/user/prod/www/devcode/manage.py celery status

produces:

Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.

Apparently I missed something fundamential, but after 2 days trying I need to ask :(

Comment: Please let me know if you found a way to resolve this problem.